# Add constraint to make column unique per group of rows

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints, unique-index, partial-index

There is a column `status` in a Postgres table which can take only two values: `Active` and `Inactive`.

One of the columns is named `userid`. The table can have multiple rows with the same `userid` but at most one of them can have `status = 'Active'`. I need only one or no `status` as `Active` per `userid`. How can I create a constraint with this condition? I couldn't find any help from the Postgres documentation.

Comment: Better add column `IsActive` of boolean type instead of storing `VARCHAR` or if you have more statuses use INT type and add lookup table.

Comment: Thats a better alternative but I can't change it as whole database structure is following this.

Comment: So, there can be more than on records in this table with the same userid ? Than what is the meaning/intention of this table, some kind of status log?

Comment: @joop its analogus to chat status. One user can save multiple status in database but can use only one at a time.

Comment: I don't know what "chat status" is. You could add some sample data to your question to show what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`status` should really be [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html). Cheaper, cleaner.

Either way, you can impose your rule with a [**partial unique index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html).

To allow zero or one row with `status = 'Active'` ***in the whole table***:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_active_uni ON tbl (status)
WHERE status = 'Active';
```

To allow zero or one row with `status = 'Active'` ***per `userid`***, make `userid` the indexed column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_userid_active_uni ON tbl (userid)
WHERE status = 'Active';
```

Null values in `userid` do not trigger unique violations, because two null values are not considered equal - at all, or by default since **Postgres 15** which added the **`NULLS NOT DISTINCT`** clause. If you don't want that, set the column [`NOT NULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#id-1.5.4.6.6), or see:

- **[Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)**
- [How to add a conditional unique index on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917065/how-to-add-a-conditional-unique-index-on-postgresql/8918141#8918141)

#### Why use an index and not a constraint?

Addressing your [question in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495479/add-constraint-to-make-column-unique-per-group-of-rows/34495621?noredirect=1#comment56733136_34495621): This is an index, not a [`CONSTRAINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html).

The index for the first case is ***tiny***, holding one or no row.
The index for the second case holds one row per existing `userid`, but it's the ***cheapest and fastest way***, in addition to being clean and safe. You would need an index to check on other rows in any case to make this fast.

You cannot have a `CHECK` constraint check on other rows - at least not in a clean, reliable fashion. There are ways I would **certainly not recommend** for this case:

- [Trigger vs. check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409952/trigger-vs-check-constraint/18411888#18411888)
- [How to avoid a cyclic dependency (circular reference) between 3 tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124019/3684)
- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75635/3684)

If you use a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(userid, status)` (which is also implemented with a unique index internally!), you cannot make it *partial*, and *all* combinations are enforced to be unique. You *could* still use this if you work with `status IS NULL` for all cases except the `'Active'` case. But that would create a much bigger index including *all* rows.

Comment: Though the solution works but isn't it an index instead of constraint. I mean creating index use extra memory to save column data in ordered fashion. Is it fine to use indexes in place of constraints?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar: See added explanation above.

Comment: The solution seems to be not working. I am adding two rows with same user id and status Inactive but on second insertion it is giving duplicate key error.
When I am checking table information using \d is showing showing...
"tb1_userid_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (userid) . With this conditon its obvious that same userid wont be accepted in the table.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar: With a unique ***constraint*** `all combinations are enforced to be unique`. I am suggesting the ***partial unique index*** instead. Please read again.

Comment: I used the same command that you gave. The unique constraint was result ot that.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ` does *not* create a `CONSTRAINT`. `tb1_userid_key` must have been created some other way.

Comment: This works when there are only two different possible values for status. But what if there's an indefinite number of groups? For example, say you have a tree-like structure and want to make sure a text identifier is unique among all the identifiers that have the same parent.

Comment: @flodin: Good question. I encourage you to ask it as *question*. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context and/or drop a comment here to link back.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter well if I ask it as a question it'll most likely get marked as a duplicate of this question. ;) But I'll try.